# Tox: per-platform configuration for tools like flake8 and pylint

Tags: python, pylint, tox, flake8

I've got tox.ini configuration for ci both in linux and windows environments, something like that:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    {py3,py27}-{test,lint}-{linux,windows}
    flake8
    check-package
skip_missing_interpreters = true
isolated_build = True
distdir = dist

[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    windows: win

# Reuse py3 and py27 envs for pylint
envdir =
    py3: {toxworkdir}/py3
    py27: {toxworkdir}/py27
    !py3-!py27: {toxworkdir}/{envname}
deps =
    py27: setuptools < 45.0.0

# test extras must include pytest and pylint
extras = test
commands =
    test: python -m pytest -c {toxinidir}/pytest.ini --junitxml=test-reports/pytest.{envname}.xml {posargs}
    lint: python -m pylint --rcfile=tox.ini src/displaylink {posargs}

[testenv:flake8]
basepython = python3
skip_install = true
deps = flake8
commands = flake8 src tests

[tool:pylint]
disable = missing-docstring,
          R,
          C,
          line-too-long
output-format = parseable
reports = no
extension-pkg-whitelist = win32api, win32gui

[flake8]
ignore = E501, E722, W503
per-file-ignores =
    # imported but unused
    __init__.py: F401
max-complexity = 10
```

Question is how may I add per-platform configuration for tools (flake and pylint) ? I need to exclude files/dirs from flake8 and pylint runs depending on os, i.e. I've got windows subdir with files that won't pass linting on linux and vice-versa

EDIT:

example of pylint errors I have on linux:

```
py3-lint-linux run-test: commands[0] | python -m pylint --rcfile=tox.ini src/displaylink

************* Module displaylink.qa.windows.registry
registry.py:4: [E0401(import-error), ] Unable to import 'win32con'
registry.py:74: [E0602(undefined-variable), reg_value_exists] Undefined variable 'WindowsError'
registry.py:82: [E0602(undefined-variable), reg_key_exists] Undefined variable 'WindowsError'
```

Comment: Hello, I'm a maintainer/author of tox. Heads up that sharing (reusing the way your comment formulates it) tox environments is not supported, and you're most likely will run in trouble. You can use the platform factors to make some part of the command platform dependent.

Comment: platform specific... linting ? what sort of stuff would change static analysis based on the platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I miss some parts of your requirement, but running `flake8` platform specific seems pretty straightforward:

```
[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    windows: win

[testenv:flake8]
deps = flake8
commands =
    linux: flake8 <linux specific directories>
    windows: flake8 <windows specific directories>
```

Also compare to the [official documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/platform.html).

Comment: I was hoping it's possible to alter configuration under `[flake8]` or `[tool:pylint] `, but modyfing commandline seems good enough ;)